# How to show current google account when sending email from third-party website?

Tags: gmail

Google allows easy access to multiple google accounts, which is very convenient in and of itself. However, it gets confusing when you are trying to send an email using a link or even the "send link" function of a browser from a third party website. In the gmail compose window that pops up in such case doesn't provide any clue as to which gmail account you'll be sending that particular email from.

Is there an easy way to tell if you are sending an email from the intended gmail account?

Comment: Could you provide an example of such a "send link"?

Comment: Well, there are many examples, but let me start with a bookmarklet that I have on all my browser:  javascript:location.href='mailto:?SUBJECT='+document.title+'&BODY='+escape(location.href);  With this bookmarklet, you can send the link to the current webpage to anybody you want.

Comment: I'll also try to find other examples, but any webpage with an "mailto:" hyperlink would bring about the same situation, I believe.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using, and what application is your default email client?

Comment: OS: Windows 7; My default email client is the browser. When I invoke a "send email" function (by clicking on a mailto: link for example), the gmail compose window pops up in the browser.